# Alternative phrase for "breaking the glass ceiling"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, slang, idiom-requests, metaphors

I’d like to say something like:  The prominence of IT has led to significant job creation while also helping migrants break the glass ceiling.

Topic is on migrants and IT.  Particularly, those from a non-English speaking background, where they have difficulty progressing their careers.  The advancing role of IT has led to many minorities reaching higher levels at faster rates than other specialties and industries.

Is there another manner of referring to "breaking the glass ceiling" that doesn't involve use of the term "glass ceiling"?

Or perhaps a shorthand phrase?

Comment: It would help if you explain the actual phenomenon you want to describe. "Breaking the glass ceiling" might be used to refer to a woman being the *first* woman in a traditionally make-dominated field, or managing to make a salary that's slightly less disparate than the average, or making a salary that's actually commensurate, or being promoted to a role that's still traditionally male-dominated (even if she's not the first) etc. And it could apply to members of other under-represented groups, too. What, exactly, do *you* have in mind?

Comment: Breaking the glass ceiling is for anyone at all reaching the top level  in a company: CEO, CFO, COO, chairman, and whatever other C's they ***invent***, like CIO.

Answer (score 1):

- reaching the top of the corporate ladder
- get to the top of the company
- reaching the executive suite

[women and the executive suite](https://www.google.com/search?ei=E7NMW4GOGKG5gge5x5fgAg&q=women%20%2B%20getting%20into%20the%20executive%20suite&oq=women%20%2B%20getting%20into%20the%20executive%20suite&gs_l=psy-ab.3...288525.296640.0.297098.44.42.2.0.0.0.179.3987.32j10.42.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.16.1299...0j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i10k1j0i22i30k1j0i13i30k1.0.p5EIoaE38d8)

Comment: OP's edit has rendered this answer pretty useless.